# jQuery: Change color of form input when value was edited

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have to change the font color of an jQuery UI Select when the value was edited. The DOM looks like this:

```
<dd>
    <select class="filter large" name="xx" style="display: none;">
        <option value="0">--</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3" selected="selected">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
    </select>
    <a class="ui-selectmenu ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-selectmenu-dropdown" id="undefined-button" role="button" href="#" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="undefined-menu" style="width: 161px;">
    <span class="ui-selectmenu-status">3</span>
    <span class="ui-selectmenu-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span></a>
</dd>
```

This is my Jquery code:

```
$('select').change(function() {
  $('span.ui-selectmenu-status').css("color","red");
});
```

Which works, but it is changing all selectBoxes, because I have no idea how to just change the color of the edited Select?

Comment: Find a selector relative to the current `select` with `$(this)`. Something like `$(this).siblings('.ui-selectmenu-status')`.

Comment: @elclanrs, it's an answer, not a comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no correct answer here yet:

This:

```
$('select').change(function() {
    $('span.ui-selectmenu-status').css("color","red");
});
```

Should be:

```
$('select').change(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('span.ui-selectmenu-status').css("color","red");
});
```

This utilizes traversing through [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/), and [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Answer (score 3):

In simple jquery this works

```
$('select').change(function() {
    $(this).find('option:selected').css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

Comment: Would work with "normal" selectboxes thanks. But not with JQ UI Select (;

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the color of siblings of the selectbox only you should use this

```
$('select').change(function(){
  $(this).find('span.ui-selectmenu-status').css('color','red');
})
```

but if you want to change the color of some specific checkboxes you should add a class to them

```
 $('.boxes').change(function(){
      $(this).find('span.ui-selectmenu-status').css('color','red');
    })
```

EDIT: this one works

```
    $('select').change(function(){
       $('body').find('span.ui-selectmenu-status').css('color','red');
    })
```

this will look for any spans with class ui-selectmenu-status inside the body element, that's how find works.

or you can just do this

```
        $('select').change(function(){
           $('span.ui-selectmenu-status').css('color','red');
        })
```

Comment: I altough though your first suggestion would work, but it doesnt. No idea why jquery does not select the next span

Comment: try with $('select').change(function(){
  $(this).siblings('span.ui-selectmenu-status').css('color','red');
})

Comment: does not work.. if i console.log the found object, it returns the select element not the span (;

Comment: ofcourse it won't work because the spans are not nested in the select, and the find function searches for the span INSIDE the select. Let me edit the answer with the proper code

Comment: hehe, this will change all selects :-) i want to change the used select box seems more tricky than expected (;

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

`$(this).next('a').find('span.ui-selectmenu-status').css('color','red');`